# A followed by "not A" followed by B

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will will capture arbitrary stuff between (literal) AA and (literal) BB, with the restriction that it will only match on the AA closest to BB.

For example, given:

```
AA stuff1 BB
```

it will capture '`stuff1`',  but given

```
AA stuff1 AA stuff2 BB
```

it will capture '`stuff2`' and not '`stuff1 AA stuff2`'.

#### a possible solution

With a little help from the awesome [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/#javascript) I've come up with the following:

```
/AA((?:.(?!AA))+)BB/
```

It uses negative lookahead to exclude any match that ends in AA.  This works -- and I'm okay with this -- but is there a better way?

#### updates

AA and BB are tokens that (may) contain spaces, such as "Due Date" and "Bill Date".  So \w and its friends won't help here.

'stuff' may span multiple lines.

There is only one instance of BB in the source string.

I'm working in javascript, but I'd prefer not to use RegEx quirks of any specific language.  Of course, you need [^] to match 'any char including newline' in javascript, so that's permitted.

I added spaces around '`stuff1`' etc to show that yes, it should capture the spaces.

Comment: Your regex will match `AAAABB` - is that OK?

Comment: `\bAA\b((?:(?!\bAA\b).)+)\bBB\b` this would be the best solution IMO

Comment: Are the spaces in your examples part of your spec.? I.e. are AA and BB whole words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use lookahead at all here - this is [good enough](https://regex101.com/r/oU2cG4/3) for the two test cases below:

```
/.*AA(.*?)BB/

AA stuff1 AA stuff2 BB blabla  # matches ` stuff2 `
AA stuff3 AA stAAuff4 BB # matches `uff4 `
```

Comment: The outer parentheses, the external "anything" matches, and the `/g` flag are obviously redundant.  So `AA(.*?)BB`

Comment: @tripleee You need the leading `.*` to force the match as far to the right as possible. Of course this assumes one match per line.

Comment: @tripleee: Yeah, thanks - I added the parentheses to be able to do `(?: ... )*` to get multiple matches from one line. `/g` is (just like `/m`) required in the sample, but not when matching here.

Comment: Yeah. This won't match 'stuff1' and 'stuff2' in e.g. 'AA stuff1 BB blah AA stuff2 BB', but again the spec. isn't clear.

Comment: @KingMob: As per update of OP, that case won't occur. Thus, I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Agreed. Just needs making multiline friendly.

Comment: @KingMob: You'll notice that the example I linked to is already multiline friendly :)

Comment: Oh, I meant replacing `.` with `[^]`, as per the OP's request (though they already know to do that, and I've already upvoted :-)).

Comment: Yep - it appears no lookahead needed.  Not sure why I convinced myself that `.*?` would be "too lazy", but that does the job.  Thanks for the simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty reasonable. Another way would be

```
/AA[^A](?:[^A]|.[^A])*BB/
```

Note that I added the first `[^A]` so that `AAAxBB` will get you a match of `AAxBB` and not the entire string (as this is actually the closer `AA` of the two).

Comment: That won't match 'AABB', but I can't tell from the Q. if that should be a match or not.

Comment: @KingMob, as OP said that his regex does what he wants and it has `+` and not `*` in it, we should assume that it shouldn't match `AABB`.

Comment: @KingMob: AABB won't match, at least according to the pattern in the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh Sure, I'm not saying this solution is necessarily wrong, just that I don't find the spec. clear. AAABB does match according the OP's regexp. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can improve on your regex by using `\b` and putting lookahead before consuming a character, rather than consuming and then checking.

```
\bAA\b((?:(?!\bAA\b).)+)\bBB\b
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aH3xV0/1)

Comment: Dunno. Should there be further constraints such as multiple matches per line or zero characters between AA and BB, then this general approach will, I think, be the way to go.

Comment: @nhahtdh No it doesn't. The OP's regexp won't match 'AABB'. And it consumes an arbitrary character before the negative lookahead so it will match 'AAABB' in its entirety.